# override options in beamertheme.sty

Tags: themes

Let me start with `mwe`:

**beamerthemeMwe.sty**

```
%Mwe
\mode<presentation>
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% COLOUR AND FONT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\definecolor{PurpleD-A100}{HTML}{B388FF}
\definecolor{dcol}{named}{PurpleD-A100}
\usecolortheme[named=dcol]{structure}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=dcol}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{bg=dcol,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=dcol}
```

**mwe.tex**

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{try}{HTML}{ff0000}
\definecolor{dcol}{named}{try}
\usetheme{Mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Hello
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The problem is,the `dcol` defined in theme should be the default color, and I should be able to change the default color from my tex file.

But, here, I am getting the `purple`, even after defining a `dcol` in tex.
How I can make the `dcol` in `tex` to override the value given in `sty`?

Comment: It looks like you have `\usetheme{Mwe}` *after* `\definecolor{dcol}{named}{try}`, so the theme overrides your customization, not the other way around.

Comment: oh...sure! thats an mistake. But, even if I swap positions, it does not obey item bullets etc. Can you please check?